# Как реализовать цикличное выполнение кода?

Tags: python, telebot

Нужно чтобы кусочек кода повторялся когда боту отправляют голосовое сообщение

Накидал что-то такое:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['voice'])
def downloading(message):
    upd = bot.get_updates()
    last_upd = upd[-1]
    voice_message_id = last_upd.message.voice.file_id
    url = bot.get_file_url(voice_message_id)
    print(voice_message_id)
    wget.download(url, directory)
```

Но возникает [проблема](https://prnt.sc/r82et7) при попытке получить обновление. 
wget работает исправно

Comment: Какая проблема?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/r82et7